# How to convert the list so that it should contains unique names with their different values?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, set

```
votess = [['Y AFGHANISTAN','Y INDIA','Y NEPAL','N UNITED STATES'], ['Y AFGHANISTAN','N INDIA','Y NEPAL','      MALI','Y UNITED STATES'], ['N AFGHANISTAN','Y INDIA','Y NEPAL', '      MONGOLIA',' N UNITED STATES']]
```

expected output,

[image: 1]

I have tried this way but it does not work

```
lis = []
for votes in votess:
    row_to_be_appended = ()
    for vote in votes:
        row_to_be_appended[vote[2:]] = vote[0]
        lis.append(row_to_be_appended)
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Are you getting an error? If you are getting some result, what result are you getting? Please add some more detail to your question to make it clearer where you are getting stuck.

Comment: Looks like your expected output is in CSV or XLSX format? Is this the expected output format?

Comment: View notebook:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1v1Yrp_ibGdqOukJ8H0e9na9hNbboEjNr?usp=sharing

It shows multiple column of same name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also do this with pandas.

Here is the solution:

```
import pandas as pd
votes = [
    ["Y AFGHANISTAN", "Y INDIA", "Y NEPAL", "N UNITED STATES"],
    ["Y AFGHANISTAN", "N INDIA", "Y NEPAL", "      MALI", "Y UNITED STATES"],
    ["N AFGHANISTAN", "Y INDIA", "Y NEPAL", "      MONGOLIA", " N UNITED STATES"],
]
flatten_votes = [vote for vote_list in votes for vote in vote_list]
votes_df = (
    pd.Series(flatten_votes)
    .str.replace(r"^\s", "")
    .str.split(r"\s+", expand=True, n=1)
)
votes_df.columns = ["judge", "type"]
votes_df.loc[:, "appear_index"] = votes_df.groupby("type").cumcount()
result = votes_df.pivot(
    index="appear_index", columns="type", values="judge"
).fillna("")
print(result)
```

Output is:

```
type         AFGHANISTAN INDIA MALI MONGOLIA NEPAL UNITED STATES
appear_index                                                    
0                      Y     Y                   Y             N
1                      Y     N                   Y             Y
2                      N     Y                   Y             N
```

Answer (score 1):

```
votess = [['Y AFGHANISTAN','Y INDIA','Y NEPAL','N UNITED STATES'], ['Y AFGHANISTAN','N INDIA','Y NEPAL','      MALI','Y UNITED STATES'], ['N AFGHANISTAN','Y INDIA','Y NEPAL', '      MONGOLIA',' N UNITED STATES']]


lis = []
for votes in votess:
    row_to_be_appended = {}
    for vote in votes:
        row_to_be_appended[vote[2:]] = vote[0]
    lis.append(row_to_be_appended)
print(lis)
```

Comment: You still need a way to align countries in columns. I would use a pandas DataFrame. Or it can also be done by populating a set with country names while in the inner loop and after you're done parsing you can loop country names, and loop rows getting the value.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will solve your problem:

```
from collections import defaultdict

votess = [['Y AFGHANISTAN',
           'Y INDIA',
           'Y NEPAL',
           'N UNITED STATES'],
          ['Y AFGHANISTAN',
           'N INDIA',
           'Y NEPAL',
           '      MALI',
           'Y UNITED STATES'],
          ['N AFGHANISTAN',
           'Y INDIA',
           'Y NEPAL',
           '      MONGOLIA',
           ' N UNITED STATES']]

v_dic = defaultdict()

for vote in votess:
    for v in vote:
        if v[2:] in v_dic:
            v_dic[v[2:]] = [v_dic[v[2:]], v[0]]
        else:
            v_dic[v[2:]] = v[0]

for v in v_dic.keys():
    print("{}->{}".format(v.strip(), v_dic[v]))
```

Output:

```
AFGHANISTAN->[['Y', 'Y'], 'N']
INDIA->[['Y', 'N'], 'Y']
NEPAL->[['Y', 'Y'], 'Y']
UNITED STATES->['N', 'Y']
MALI-> 
MONGOLIA-> 
UNITED STATES->
```